# Send message every x hrs on Discord in every group/guild

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

currently I'm working on a event-bot and that bot is used on a few groups in Discord.
So right now I have this code:

```
if (command === "init")
  {
    //var d = new Date();
    //var n = d.getHours();
    message.channel.send("BunnBot starting...");
    var interval = setInterval (function () {
  message.channel.send("123")
  //message.channel.send(n);
}, 30 * 1000);
  }
```

The Problem is, that this command only works for the current group, means that in any other group I would have to use the init command as well.

How can I solve it? How can I make that my Bot send a message to every group?

Edit:
Okay, I changed the code a bit and I'm now using this:
Okay, here's my new code and now I'm stuck with an error message, that send is not a function

```
client.on("ready", () => {
console.log('Logged in as BunnyBot');
setInterval (function () {
    client.guilds.forEach(() => { //for each guild the bot is in
        let defaultChannel = "";
        client.guilds.forEach((channel) => {
            if(channel.type == "text" && defaultChannel == "") {
           if(channel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has("SEND_MESSAGES")) {
               defaultChannel = channel;
           }
            }
        })
        message.defaultChannel.send("Message here"); //send it to whatever channel the bot has permissions to send on
        console.log("Sending Messages");
   })
}, 1 * 1000);
})
```

Problem: Now I get an error message, that send is not a function.

Comment: By group do you mean `guild` or `server`?

Comment: There's a difference? Someone told me that every Discord-Group is called a guild. Some call it server, right?

Comment: @Xanar you are correct in naming them guilds and servers (atleast for discord). Something you haven't clarified in your question is which channel in the guild should your message me sent to? Otherwise, it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Generally I want the message to be in the #general-channel. Problem is, that Discord doesn't have the default-room anymore, so maybe the #general-channel is called #the-lounge or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well ignoring the `#general-channel` situation for now, you can accomplish all guild posting, by doing:

Edit:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client();
bot.on("ready", () => {
    bot.guilds.forEach((guild) => { //for each guild the bot is in
         let defaultChannel = "";
         guild.channels.forEach((channel) => {
               if(channel.type == "text" && defaultChannel == "") {
               if(channel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has("SEND_MESSAGES")) {
                   defaultChannel = channel;
               }
               }
         })
         setInterval (function () {
              defaultChannel.send("Message here") //send it to whatever channel the bot has permissions to send on
         }, 30 * 1000);
   })
})
```

This code should send to all guilds your bot is in, the message you want with the interval you want, although maybe not **the channel** that you want.

Comment: That is awesome! Well, I could force a default-channel by adding a command like b!default <Room-Name>, that will then force the bot to write in that specific channel.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but now I get the following error:

`ReferenceError: guilds is not defined`

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem! Good luck with the rest of your bot!

Comment: Hi, I am trying to use the code but I have version 12.x. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The node.js version 12.x changed some things, to fix your code you need to edit a few things:

```
  bot.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => { //for each guild the bot is in
    let defaultChannel = "";
    guild.channels.cache.forEach((channel) => {
          if(channel.type == "text" && defaultChannel == "") {
          if(channel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has("SEND_MESSAGES")) {
              defaultChannel = channel;
            }
          }
    })
    setInterval (function () {
         defaultChannel.send("Message here") //send it to whatever channel the bot has permissions to send on
    }, 5000);})
```

Answer (score 0):

just a simple solution, might not be the best one, but its a solution.

```
while(0 == 0) {
    channel = client.channels.cache.get('channel-id');
    channel.send("message you want to sent")
    sleep.sleep(seconds);
}
```

you will need the npm package known as sleep

npm install sleep